# Which is better for file download? Why?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

My current task for our web app is to download a CSV file when the user clicks a button on the UI.

I was able to format the data into a CSV fine (it's just a big string). But being a JavaScript idiot, I found some code on the web that showed how to download the file. I found several methods, but chose one that looked the most straight-forward.

This is what it looks like:

```
  var pom = document.createElement( 'a' );
  pom.setAttribute( 'href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(csvFile) );
  pom.setAttribute( 'download', filename );

  if( document.createEvent ) {
    var event = document.createEvent( 'MouseEvents' );
    event.initEvent( 'click', true, true );
    pom.dispatchEvent( event );
  }
  else {
    pom.click();
  }
```

The problem is, I don't know what the difference between the code in the `if` and the `else` is. Yes, I can see that the `if` version does a mouse event version of a click, and the else just calls a click function, but I don't know why the browser would use one or the other.

And here's the thing: I've tried both versions in Chrome... and both *work*. Just the `if` version works. Just the `else` version works. Chrome is the only browser we're required to support.

Do I need both? If not, which one is preferable and why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's trying to deal with browsers that don't support `createEvent` [MDN compatability table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createEvent#Browser_compatibility) and [Can I use `createEvent`](https://www.caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-api_document_createevent).

If you don't need to support those browsers, you can just assume it's there and use the first block.

Comment: Isn't it the other way around? Seems like it's handling if the `click()` method won't work. Is there a reason to prefer `createEvent` over simply `click()` if the other is present?

Comment: I was wondering the same thing as @Jared Farrish. But regardless, thanks for the explanation! I would think that one line vs. three would be preferable, but it looks like the longer version is preferred for some reason. Like I said, both versions work in Chrome.

Comment: @JaredFarrish I would assume that in this case either will work.  One thing that dispatching a created event has over just `.click` is that you are able to set [every property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent#Properties) of the click event including where in the element the click took place.  This doesn't matter for this case though and you're right, you might want to favor the simpler API since both work.